# Django - model and serializer class, the best way to do

Tags: python, django, serialization

firstly let me explain the situation. I have a model that basically have a title and a TextField that will save a json:

```
class Content(UUIDObject):
    title = models.CharField(_(u"Title"), max_length=300)
    custom_fields_json = models.TextField(_(u"Settings"))
```

To create this json, I must use a serializer class, from django rest framework. This class doesn't have a link to any model.

```
class ConfigSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    provider = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    provider_id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
```

The class above must be used to offer the user a form so he can fill `title` (from content model), `provider` and `provider_id`. The resulting json from the serializer class will be stored at `custom_fields_json`. The serializer class used in dynamic and I have the logic to return it working properly.

Currently I have a CreateView/UpdateView and adapting the code from [this guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/) I can render the form with all the fields.. but then I just can't get the json from the serializer, etc...

I'm starting to think that this is the wrong way of doing it. I would like to ask to guys with more experience if there is a better way of doing it, and what would it be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the ModelSerializer:

```
class ConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('title', 'custom_fields_json')
```

The serializer can give you a dict. Also read about ModelViewSets in django rest framework, they can significally minimize your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I add the extra fields of the serializer class that is used to fill the custom_fields_json?

Comment: You mean when saving? You can add a validate_<fieldname> method in your serializer. It is run whenever you pass the fields to populate the table (model). So you can turn the dict you pass into a json in this method. I may be wrong, so just to be sure check out this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

Comment: OK. This serializer class, that fills the custom_fields_json, I can't add anything to it. It is from another module of another company. I can just count on .is_valid. I mean adding this class to the form and getting the values the user filled